# browser network tab resource limit

Tags: google-chrome, networking

I do not speak English well. Understand me.
I have a question. For resources on the Network tab,.
During the test, if the transferred and resources shown in the picture exceed 50GB, the network err is displayed. No more response can be received.
Please let me know if there is any documentation on this. I can't find
Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The image is broken. In words, it points to transferred and resources at the bottom of the network tab. chrome brower...

Comment: You mean Developer Tools in Chrome Browser. Here check this link and please fix that image link so  your question can keep legit at some point. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/understanding-resource-timing

Comment: @ismetguzelgun I fixed the picture. Does it have anything to do with the document you gave me?

Comment: Could you also share your network err ?

Comment: @ismetguzelgun There are two kinds of errors. Each time I try it shows a different error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below. `Network.setDataSizeLimitsForTest` argument could work for your needs.

[Resource](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-setDataSizeLimitsForTest)

Comment: Thank you. Let's take a look at this document.